# How to animate contour plot in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have 32x21 matrix with x axis increment of one parameter (2 to 64 in steps of 2) and y axis increment of n other parameter,in steps of two again. I can plot it as contour plot, but I was wondering if there is a way to have contour plot as animation/movie.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to place your plot in a for loop which iterates through all the contours? Use [drawnow](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/drawnow.html)
e.g.

```
hold on
for ii = 2:2:64
    %do your plotting here
    %use "pause" if too fast
    drawnow
end
```

This should update the figure every iteration.

Also see [this](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/animation-techniques.html)

Comment: You dont need hold on and hold off inside. You do need `drawnow` though.

Comment: I added hold on, just in case she had multiple plots for every "frame". Should have specified.

Comment: I mean, you need a hold on *outside*

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer but it did not help. It all appears very fast even with pause (5).

Comment: That would be 5ms

Comment: Try to run with different pause:
`pause(500) % 500ms` or `pause(1000) % 1s`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help again, unfortunately that didn't help either. with pause(500) or pause(1000) it plots the whole figure ad then Matlab goes busy forever.

Comment: Terribly sorry, but you are right. In MATLAB pause needs seconds. I am surprised pause(5) did not work. Could you try pause(1), adding a `tic` at the beginning of you loop and a `toc` at the end of it?